# How can I check if I logged in a website (e.g. LinkedIn) using HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

This is a newbie question in HtmlUnit. I have used the code I found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127360/login-to-linkedin-using-htmlunit-and-navigate-to-connections-web-page) to log into LinkedIn, but when I open the page with Chrome the current user is logged out. Can I  check if I have indeed logged in the site?

Answer (score 0):

In general the content of the page somehow changes, when you are logged in.
So you could simply log the source of the page after you logged in.
(If ajax is used on the page, you need to wait some time so that the javascript can modify the page)

use the `.toXml()`-method to get the html source. You can also save this in a file e.g. t.html and open it in a browser (active content and css will most probably not work, but you can still see enough in most cases to determine, if login worked or what is on the page after the login).